# Getting started with Netbeans and Selenium

Tags: java, netbeans, selenium

I want to create a new project in Netbeans that will be used for testing a web application using Selenium 2. I am not sure how to get started.

Is there any simple step by step tutorial to follow for Netbeans + Selenium?

What type of new project do I need to create in Netbeans so that I can run tests?

Comment: http://javadude.wordpress.com/2010/03/08/quick-tutorial-netbeans-selenium-hudson/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a New java project in your IDE.

Download the Selenium Standalone server [here](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list.)

Put the jar file in the lib and Start to create your Selenium test cases.

If you want to run it on Chrome then download the `chromedriver.exe` file [here](http://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/downloads/list)

For to run on IE download the `IEDriverServer.exe` for respective bit version [here](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver)

**Sample code:**

```
 WebDriver driver  = new FirefoxDriver();
 driver.get("URL");
 //Do some actions
 driver.quit();
```

Comment: I saw this solution in another posting and just could not believe it was so simple as just including the .jar file.  Sure enough, it really IS that simple!

Comment: @Eva I'm sure it is more than enough to start your beginning selenium test cases.

Answer (score 1):

Check out "[Quick Tutorial: Netbeans + Selenium + Hudson](http://javadude.wordpress.com/2010/03/08/quick-tutorial-netbeans-selenium-hudson/)"; it contains a screen shot also.

Also see "[Selenium Tutorial for Beginner/Tips for Experts](http://www.jroller.com/selenium/)"

Comment: @coure2011, if you have any query replyme

Comment: its saying to just add library selenium-java-2.30.0.zip, is it enough? what about the selenium server? for that Can I download plugin to autostart/stop?

Comment: @coure2011 no at the moment you add the library then after you have to check .